# two jquery toggle Got so far with it

Tags: jquery, html

Trying a hide/show in jquery and i can get the first one to work but when I try the second one i get into the function and can see the value past but it does nothing (actually hides the first div)

Below is first my jquery. Followed by my html. As you can see I have two alerts and I get into both of them but for the second one. Nothing happens.

```
//      SHOW/HIDE CONTENT
        $(function() {
//          SHOW HIDE FURNITURE TYPE SECTIONS
            $("[name=radioShow]").click(function(){
                alert('First to here!');


                    $('.toHide').hide();
                    $("#block-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
               });

//          SHOW HIDE FOAM REPLACEMENT SECTION   
            $("[name=radioShowFoam]").click(function(){
                alert('Second should show sommat!');
                alert($(this).val());

                    $('.toHide').hide();
                    $(".foam-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
               });
        });
```

THe below now is my html.

```
<!--TYPE OF CHAIR-->
<div id="radio">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioShow" value="1"><label for="radio1">Dining Chair</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioShow" value="2"><label for="radio2">Stool</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radioShow" value="3"><label for="radio3">Ottoman</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radioShow" value="4"><label for="radio4">Louis XV style</label>
</div>

<!--DINING CHAIR SECTION-->
<div id="block-1" class="toHide" style="display:none; width:100%;">
    <!--BASIC CHARGE FOR A DINING CHAIR IS FIRSTLY ADDED TO THE TEXT BOX BELOW-->
    Price:<input id='text' value='10' />

    <!--BELOW CODE WILL CALL THE FUNCTION TO TAKE THE VALUE OF WHATEVER HAS JUST BEEN CLICKED-->
    <!--onchange='go( this.options[this.selectedIndex].value );-->

    <h2>Dining Chair</h2>


    <div class="radio">
      <label class="orderLabel">Is the base Removable?</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio5" name="radio" value="y"><label for="radio5">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio6" name="radio" value="n"><label for="radio6">No</label>
    </div>


    <div class="radio">
      <label>Number of removable bases/squabs per chair?</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio7" name="radio1" value="1"><label for="radio7">1</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio8" name="radio1" value="2"><label for="radio8">2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio">
    <label for="spinner">Number of chairs:</label>
    <input id="spinner" name="value"><button id="setvalue">Set value to 0</button><br />  
    </div>

    <div class="radio">
      <label>Foam replacement required?</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio09" name="radioShowFoam" value="1"><label for="radio09">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio10" name="radioShowFoam" value="0"><label for="radio10">No</label>
    </div>

           <!--IF YES-->
           <div class="foam-1 toHide" style="display:none; width:100%;">
               NEED FOAM
           </div>
           <!--END OF IF YES-->

           <!--IF NO-->
           <div id="foam-no" class="toHide" style="display:none; width:100%;">
               DONT NEED FOAM
           </div>
           <!--END OF IF NO-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your HTML.

You have a parent div with an id of "Block-1" and a class of "toHide".

In your first function you are showing the "Block-1" element which will work as it's the parent element.

Yet for your second function displaying the child div "foam-1" or "foam-no" you first hide all elements with class "toHide", hiding the parent as well.

then you are toggling the "foam-1" element to show, yet the parent is invisible.

The quick and easy fix is to rename the class on the parent elements to say "blockToHide"

Your javascript then becomes:

```
//      SHOW/HIDE CONTENT
        $(function() {
//          SHOW HIDE FURNITURE TYPE SECTIONS
            $("[name=radioShow]").click(function(){
                alert('First to here!');


                    $('.blockToHide').hide();
                    $("#block-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
               });

//          SHOW HIDE FOAM REPLACEMENT SECTION   
            $("[name=radioShowFoam]").click(function(){
                alert('Second should show sommat!');
                alert($(this).val());

                    $('.toHide').hide();
                    $(".foam-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
               });
        });
```

From your HTML I gather you will have a few of these blocks disappearing and appearing I would therefore come up with a better naming strategy for the child elements "toHide" such as "toHide-1", "toHide2" etc. Or you can refer to the parent element and only hide as needed.

Hope this makes sense, otherwise let me know.